# What's causing a master-slave JK flip flop to get 'stuck'?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, schematics, flipflop

I've built a JK master-slave flip flop according to the following schematic:

[image]

Putting it into Logicly I have the following diagram:

[image]

However, regardless of which switches I change, the final two NOR gates's outputs never changes. Here's a video showing this:  https://gyazo.com/a8982643c436c6b7084d9a3eca577f13 (with a working gated SR latch above).

Is there a certain properly of this circuit that the circuit-simulator isn't taking into account? Or is the schematic I've created incorrect? I thought creating the master-slave relationship would correct the previous JK-latch error I had.

Additionally, simulating D flipflop seems fine, so curious why the feedback in the JK might be so different.

Comment: the input switches are suspect ... use SPDT switches ... connect NO to HIGh ... connect NC to LOW .... connect C to input

Comment: @jsotola could you please view the updated video? I've shown one circuit that works with that orientation. Do you think I should still change them? https://gyazo.com/a8982643c436c6b7084d9a3eca577f13

Comment: compare your circuit to the one in your previous question ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491003/master-slave-flip-flop-without-gate-delay ... they are not the same ... i am not talking about the conversion from NAND to NOR per se ... i am saying that the conversion was done incorrectly

Comment: @jsotola which part of the above is incorrect? The schematic I took from another source.

Comment: where did you get the schematic? ... a NAND  gate is equivalent to an inverted input OR gate

Comment: @jsotola here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1OC5e7Tn_o and same here http://www.circuitstoday.com/flip-flops and here https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-10/j-k-flip-flop/.

Comment: @David542 I see some a comment on Ben Eater's video that remarks about the incorrect layout in the video. In the 2nd link, it's about RS not JK. In the 3rd link, while it may work in practice (not so well in simulators in certain input cases), it's not the circuit you show in your question.

Comment: @jonk yes, it looks like he had it hooked up to the wrong input, and that was the issue in mine as well. Thank you!

Comment: @jonk finally, I figured out a good way to represent it with master-slave: http://tinyurl.com/vfk4gdr

Comment: @David542 Good to hear!

Comment: @jonk thank you! Man, that Jack Kilby is a genius!

Comment: @David542 Did you notice my initials? ;)

Comment: @jonk ha, very cool!